# Dirichlet convolutions and a formula given in Selberg's sieve

Tags: sieve-theory, dirichlet-convolution

I was reading the Selberg's sieve theorem and stumbled on one equation that I honestly cannot understand. As in theorem, we let $A$ be a set of positive integers, $\mathcal{P}$ -set of primes, let
$$
P(z) = \prod_{\substack{p \in \mathcal{P}\\ p < z}}p,
$$
define
$$
A_d := \{a \colon a \in A, d | a \}
$$
and define completely multiplicative function $f \colon \mathbb{N} \to (0,1]$ to estimate $|A_{d}|$, i.e.
$$
|A_{d}| = |A|f(d) + r(d).
$$
Moreover, define functions $g, F$ and $V$ to be
$$
g(n) = (\mu * f)(n) = \sum_{d|n}\mu(d)f\left(\frac{n}{d}\right)
$$
$$
F(n) = \left(\frac{1}{f} * \mu\right) (n) = \sum_{d|n} \frac{\mu(d)}{f\left(\frac{n}{d}\right)}
$$
$$
V(z) = \sum_{\substack{d \leq z \\ d|P(z)}} \frac{\mu^2(d)}{g(d)}.
$$
One place in the proof of Selberg's formula requires the truth of formula
$$
\sum_{\substack{d|P(z) \\ d \leq z}}\mu^2(d)F(d) = V(z).
$$
I believe it is equivalent to proving that
$$
\mu^2(n) \left( F(n) - \frac{1}{g(n)} \right) = 0.
$$
But why is that?

Comment: It means $\mu^2(n)F(n)=\mu^2(n)/g(n)$, which is a sufficient condition for that formula to hold.

Comment: Could you provide source of the formulas you listed as there are may different ways to treat Selberg's sieve.

Comment: I'm trying to make my own notes on the sieve theory but I base most of the time on memoir by Mario Sariols Quiles and An Introduction to Sieve Methods and their Applications by A. C. Cojocaru & M. R. Murty (I also use Sieve Methods by H. Iwaniec, I think it greatly helps you understand what is going on in these theorems). Actually, now I see that the formulation of the theorem written in my notes might not be completely right (I guess the function $V(z)$ should be defined as sum over values of $g$, not its reciprocals).

Comment: I highly doubt whether what you are trying to prove is true or not.

Comment: Nevermind, I get it now - had to modify the assumptions and the form of $V(z)$.